# iOS Facebook SDK 4.1: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returning false

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I've got a Swift application that was successfully using the Facebook SDK for iOS version 4.1 and until last night, everything was working properly. Then, everything turned sour and the SDK seemed to stop working with my app. I made no modifications to the Facebook app's settings or my app's code. All information needed is present in the info.plist file, and the AppDelegate calls the proper methods like

```
var fblaunch = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

as well as the openURL method required elsewhere in the delegate. However, the call to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is now returning false for no evident reason. The login button I have set up still opens Safari and displays the pertinent information about allowing my Facebook app access, but when the device comes back to my application it acts as if nothing ever happened Facebook-wise. What is going on?

Comment: What outputs when you debug around if-else clauses for the 'FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()' condition?

This should return an accessToken object where you can see its properties if you have successfully logged-in